# Getting update from DB when there is a new message

Tags: vb.net

I am designing a basic chat application.  What I have done is, when a user types a message, it is simply stored to database, then I have put a timer which checks database every second for a new message.

I want to know if there is any other way to do it, I mean instead client application to check for new message every second, is there any way that database could send notification to users whenever there is a new message?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `SqlDependency` class with SQL Server.  It is designed for a small number of clients so, if you have too many, you may need to create a middleware application that receives notifications and then broadcasts them.

Comment: Please define a little background on your application, what type of application it is desktop, web or mobile. This will be accessed within an intranet or will be available to anyone. This will help people to give you a better suggestions.

Comment: http://www.vb-tips.com/SQLChanges.aspx

Comment: Really, such project is not about DB at all. It is about Remoting, Web Sockets, etc. You should probably research how to build, or what technology to use for chat system, before asking how do it with database